# Prediction of MA(1) process

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, matrix, moving-average

Let $X_t = Z_t +\theta Z_{t-1}$, invertable, $Z_t\sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$. Consider the prediction $P_nX_{n+1} = \phi_{n1}X_n + ... + \phi_{nn}X_1$. Derive the coefficients $\phi_{n1},...\phi_{nn}$.

My attempt:

Let $R_n = (r(i-j))_{i,j=1,...n}$ be $n\times n$ matrix (here $r(\cdot)$ is covariance function) , i.e.
\begin{pmatrix}
r(0) & r(1) & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
r(1) & r(0) & r(0) & ... & 0 & 0 \\
& & ... & & \\
0 & 0 & 0&... & r(1) & r(0)
\end{pmatrix}

For MA(1) process we know that $r(0) = 1 + \theta^2$ and $r(1) = \theta$. Fors simplicy let's ignore $\sigma^2$ and let it be equal to $1$. If I will divide the matrix $R_n$ by $1+\theta^2$ (let $\frac{\theta}{1+\theta^2} = A$) we will get a new matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & A & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
A & 1 & A & ... & 0 & 0 \\
& & ... & & \\
0 & 0 & 0&... & 1 & A
\end{pmatrix}
In the end we need to solve this equation: $R_n * \phi_n = r_n$, here $\phi_n = (\phi_{n1},...\phi_{nn})', r_n = (r(1),...r(n))' = (A, 0, ..., 0))'$.

My attempt was to solve it from the bottom, i.e. saying that $\phi_{nn}$ has some unknowns walue and I get the following results:
$\phi_{n n-1} =\frac{-\phi_{nn}(1+\theta^2)}{\theta}$, $A\phi_{n n-2} + \phi_{n n-1} +A\phi_{nn} = 0 \rightarrow \phi_{n n-2} = \frac{\phi_{nn}(1+\theta^2)^2}{\theta^2} - \phi_{nn}$, $A\phi_{n n-3} + \phi_{n n-2} +A\phi_{n n-1} = 0 \rightarrow \phi_3 = (2\phi_{nn} - \frac{\phi_{nn}(1+\theta^2)^2}{\theta^2})\frac{1+\theta^2}{\theta}$...

Can someone help me to derive the general formula (expression of $\phi_{na}$, where $a={1,...,n}$), i.e. find all other values and $\phi_{n1}$?

Comment: Under normality, the conditional expectation of the new observation, given the observed observations, is the BLUP.  This involves inverting the MA(1) covariance matrix.  In the past, one would estimate this inverse by assuming the MA(1) covariance matrix was infinitely dimensional.  However, one can use the exact inverse to obtain a better 1-step ahead forecast for an MA(1) process.  See this article https://web.unbc.ca/~kumarp/aml162003.pdf